# Memcache Class still not found

Tags: php, apache, memcached, php-ini, libmemcached

Having a lot of trouble getting Memcache to work on my server.

I have:

Apached 2.4

PHP 5.5.11

Memcache 3.0.8 ts vc11 x86

I have placed the line:

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
```

In my php.ini file which is being loaded correctly with no errors:

```
C:\Web Server\PHP>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Web Server\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

If I delete php_memcache.dll from my ext directory I get errors, so it is definitely finding it and using the right php.ini file.

When I run my test page it shows php_info() with no memcache module details, and at the bottom of that page I try to create a new memcache object with:

```
$M = new Memcache();
```

But I get:

Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in C:\Web Server\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line 5

I have been Googling and trying out different versions etc etc for the past two days with 0 success.

How can I get this to work?

---

**UPDATE**

If I execute my test php file using the command line I get no errors and I am able to use Memcache functions.

Why doesn't it work properly when I use a browser??

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a pain in the arse.

Turns out I didn't put:

PHPIniDir "c:/Web Server/PHP/"

In my httpd.conf file, so it wasn't loading any php.ini file.

Once I did that it loaded the correct php.ini file and all my modules are now registered!

Hope this helps stop someone else tearing their hair out!